Slow insert from Oracle to Postgres table by dblink
I set up a connection between Oracle19c and PostgreSQL15 using dblink. Everything works fine. But when trying to insert a million rows from Oracle to Postgres, it works  very slow.
From sqlplus or sql developer - 1000 rows are inserted in 12 seconds. 100,000 rows in 20 minutes. What could be the reason? On the Postgres server itself, inserting a million records takes less than a minute. From the server, where Oracle installed, through the isql utility and Postgres odbc, is about the same. Maybe HS agent is the reason?

You should log what actually happens on the PostgreSQL side. Perhaps those 100000 rows are inserted in 100000 INSERT statements, and each is a single transaction because of PostgreSQL's autocommit behavior. In that case, run the statements in an explicit connection.
Another explanation might be the network latency.
